# Problem with the Cooley-Numerov Method for Solving the Radial Nuclear Schodinger Equation in the Born-Oppenheimer Approximation

Tags: schroedinger-equation, integration, eigenvalue, molecules, vibrations

I have been trying to implement a solver for the radial nuclear Schodinger equation in the Born-Oppenheimer approximation using a similar method to R. J. Le Roy's LEVEL program[1].

I have as input a set of values for the electronic potential {U<sub>i</sub>} at regularly spaced intervals of separation {R<sub>i</sub>}, with the potential defined such that U<sub>inf</sub> = 0. From this I proceed following the procedure outlined by Cooley in Ref. [2].

First I generate a set of guess eigenvalues by fitting a Morse potential to the input potential {U<sub>i</sub>} and taking the analytical solutions to this as my starting guess eigenvalues.

With these in place I proceed to integrate inwards from the most separated value (R<sub>n+1</sub>), generating each subsequent P<sub>n</sub> from the proceeding P<sub>n+1</sub> using the following formula (Eq. 2.9 in Ref. [2]).

P<sub>n+1</sub> = a small arbitrary number
*(This is the first point in the integration, the largest R<sub>n</sub>)*

P<sub>n</sub> = P<sub>n+1</sub> * EXP( R<sub>n+1</sub> * SQRT( U<sub>n+1</sub> - E ) - R<sub>n</sub> * SQRT( U<sub>n</sub> - E ) )

This integration proceeds until P<sub>m</sub> < P<sub>m+1</sub> at which point the method begins an outward integration to meet at this (m) point.

This all appears simple and reasonable, but in practice I am confronted with a problem I cannot see how to solve.

At some point the value for the potential becomes more negative than the guess eigenvalue, U<sub>n+1</sub> < E, resulting in a complex number. If I proceed then my trial wave function becomes complex, and there is no way to define P<sub>n</sub> < P<sub>n+1</sub>.

I have tried to solve this by defining the potential as 0 at it's minimum *r<sub>e</sub>* (positive everywhere else) and the eigenvalues as negative. In this way the term in the SQRT is always positive. However, in doing this P increases exponentially as we integrate inwards, diverging upwards to a large value, never attaining a maximum.

To my reasoning some insight is gained by viewing the equation as a ratio:

P<sub>n</sub>/P<sub>n+1</sub> = EXP( R<sub>n+1</sub> * SQRT( U<sub>n+1</sub> - E ) - R<sub>n</sub> * SQRT( U<sub>n</sub> - E ) )

Thus we see that at some point (my instinct says when the potential crosses the trial eigenvalue) the term inside the EXP will become negative, the ratio becomes < 1.0 and the wave function begins decreasing. Though in practice I never see this without terms becoming complex.

**So my question is:**

Does anyone have any insight into this problem? 
Can anyone suggest any resources that I may have missed to help explain this solver to me?

Many thanks.

1. http://scienide2.uwaterloo.ca/~rleroy/level/
2. Cooley, J. W. Math. Comput. 1961, 15 (76), 363–374. (http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1961-15-076/S0025-5718-1961-0129566-X/S0025-5718-1961-0129566-X.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with some careful head scratching and reading.

It turns out I misread the paragraph after Eq. (2.9). This is NOT the integration formula, just a statement of the boundary condition value for P as R -> inf and U -> constant. It provides the first two values needed for the rest of the inwards integration.

The correct formula to use for both the inwards and outwards integration are either Eq. (2.4) or Eq. (2.6).

With that the algorithm flows as intended.